# Migrate from SQL Server-based code-first EF to SQLite EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've developed a project based on EF6 code first technology and it used SQL Server as database engine.

Now I want to change the database and migrate to SQLite, but I want to do this with minimum effort.

Now my Question is How do I force EF to use SQLite instead of SQL Server?

because I'm a newbie in EF I will be appreciated if you explain this in very clear steps.

Additional Info : 
this is my main class code :

```
class PManagerContext :DbContext
{
    public PManagerContext(bool IsRemote, DbConnection dbconn, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(dbconn, contextOwnsConnection)
    {         
        if (!IsRemote)
        {            
             Database.SetInitializer(new PManagerDBInitializerLocal());           
        }
        else
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new PManagerDBInitializerRemote());      
        }

    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InternalP> InternalPs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogInOut> LogInOuts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PLog> PLogs { get; set; }
}
```

above class use DBInitializer as figured below :

```
class PManagerDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PManagerContext>
{        
    protected override void Seed(PManagerContext context)
    {
      //seedding      
    }
}
class PManagerDBInitializerLocal : IDatabaseInitializer<PManagerContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(PManagerContext context)
    {
    //initializing

    } 
}
class PManagerDBInitializerRemote : IDatabaseInitializer<PManagerContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(PManagerContext context)
    {
        //initializing

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code First Migrations are not supported by the SQLite EF6 provider, so you cannot do this.

Comment: what is your alternate solution for such a this move?

Comment: Why do you want to move to SQLite?

Comment: because costumer of my application are skillless and can't install SQL Server properly. furthermore, some of them have an accounting application which uses SQLSERVER and they fear my application disrupt their data(it is funny). so they refuse using my application. from my point of view, my application is in small scale and SQLite can handle my needs. totally eliminating SQLSERVER could lead to easier application deployment. @ErikEJ

Comment: You could consider using SQL Server Compact, it does not have the same limitations (but is deprecated)

Comment: does SQL SERVER Compact match with EF? does EF Could migrate to SQL Compact easily?

Comment: It depends on how you define "easily", but yes, it is quite compatible